# How to forecast next week based on data of this week in R?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I have daily time series data. How can I forecast the next 7 days based on the data of the last 7 days in R? That means the value of this Monday should be the value of next Monday, the value of this Tuesday should be the value of next Tuesday and so on.
Can someone give me an example how to program that in R? Or is there a function for that?
Here is a short example:

```
 Day   Consumption     
  1        14   
  2        15    
  3        16
  4        13
  5        18
  6        20
  7        22
  ...
```

How can I forecast the next days always related on the consumption value of 7 days before in R? So that day 1 = day 8, day 2 = day 9, day 3 = day 10 ...

Comment: If you are searching for a multi-step ahead prediction, then you can refer this paper, 

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9225449/

If you have doubt on implementation, then you can ask further.

Comment: @debaonline4u I have edited the question. Maybe now my question is clearer. I want to implement a naive prediction in R, which always relies on the value 7 days before.